# MS Acess: Union and transpose multiple tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a number of static tables with numerous columns. They all have one common column. I would like to transpose each of these tables so that the column names become rows, the column values become rows and so that there is one "common" column. For example:

```
+---------+---+------+-----+---------+-----+
| Table 1 |   |  x1  | x2  |   x3    | x4  |
+---------+---+------+-----+---------+-----+
|         | 1 |  5   |  4  |  alpha  |  6  |
|         | 2 |  5   |  1  |  alpha  |  5  |
|         | 3 |  8   |  4  |  alpha  |  6  |
|         | 4 |  0   |  8  |  Beta   |  1  |
|         | 5 |  10  |  3  |  Beta   |  5  |
|         | 6 |  3   |  6  |  Beta   |  4  |
|         | … | …    | …   | …       | …   |
+---------+---+------+-----+---------+-----+



+---------+---+-----+-----+---------+
| Table 2 |   | y1  | y2  |   x3    |
+---------+---+-----+-----+---------+
|         | 1 |  2  |  7  |  Alpha  |
|         | 2 |  1  |  4  |  Beta   |
|         | … | …   | …   | …       |
+---------+---+-----+-----+---------+


+--------------+----+---------+------------+--------------+--------------+
| RESULT TABLE |    |   x3    | Field Name | Column Value | Source Table |
+--------------+----+---------+------------+--------------+--------------+
|              | 1  | Alpha   | x1         |  5           | Table 1      |
|              | 2  | Alpha   | x2         |  4           | Table 1      |
|              | 3  | Alpha   | x4         |  6           | Table 1      |
|              | 4  | Alpha   | x1         |  5           | Table 1      |
|              | 5  | Alpha   | x2         |  1           | Table 1      |
|              | 6  | Alpha   | x4         |  5           | Table 1      |
|              | 7  | Alpha   | x1         |  8           | Table 1      |
|              | 8  | Alpha   | x2         |  4           | Table 1      |
|              | 9  | Alpha   | x4         |  6           | Table 1      |
|              | 10 | Beta    | x1         |  0           | Table 1      |
|              | 11 | Beta    | x2         |  8           | Table 1      |
|              | 12 | Beta    | x4         |  1           | Table 1      |
|              | 13 | Beta    | x1         |  10          | Table 1      |
|              | 14 | Beta    | x2         |  3           | Table 1      |
|              | 15 | Beta    | x4         |  5           | Table 1      |
|              | 16 | Beta    | x1         |  3           | Table 1      |
|              | 17 | Beta    | x2         |  6           | Table 1      |
|              | 18 | Beta    | x4         |  4           | Table 1      |
|              | 19 |  Alpha  | y1         |  2           | Table 2      |
|              | 20 |  Alpha  | y2         |  7           | Table 2      |
|              | 21 | Beta    | y1         |  1           | Table 2      |
|              | 22 | Beta    | y2         |  4           | Table 2      |
|              | …  | …       | …          | …            | …            |
+--------------+----+---------+------------+--------------+--------------+
```

In the above example, x3 is the common column which I would like to keep. All other columns are turned into rows with their respective values.

Is this possible at all in access SQL? I am quite new and cannot find the solution as I will need to first union the two tbales, then somehow pivot it except for the x3 column.

The above is just an example, in reality each table can have many columns so I would like to try do this dynamically for any number of columns

EDIT:

I have come up with a dynamic solution. I can use VBA to create a query:

```
select x3 as x3,  x1 as [field name], [x1] as [column value], 'Table 1' as [Source Table]
UNION ALL
select x3 as x3,  x2 as [field name], [x2] as [column value], 'Table 1' as [Source Table]
...
```

This will get the first table in the correct format.

Then I can repeat for the second table and union both to get the result.

However in practice, my tables contain a lot of columns, so this query string gets very large very quickly and unfortunately microsoft access cannot handle long sql strings so gives an error that the query is too complex. Can't see any other workaround...

Comment: If you are using T-SQL from MS SQL Server you can use PIVOT operator in select statment to transpose table. That's not very straightforward but possible.

Comment: @AlexeyUsharovski I'm doing it from access - is it still possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use `apply` to unpivot and `union all`:

```
select v.x3, v.col, v.val, v.table
from t1 cross apply
     (values ('table1', 'x1', x1, x3),
             ('table1', 'x2', x2, x3),
             . . .
     ) v(table, col, val)
union all
select v.x3, v.col, v.val, v.table
from t2 cross apply
     (values ('table2', 'x1', x1, x3),
             ('table2', 'x2', x2, x3),
             . . .
     ) v(table, col, val)
. . .
```

Note that for this (or any other method) to work, the types of the columns need to be compatible.  You may need to convert to strings for this to work.

Comment: Unfortunately the columns may be in a different format which I need to keep as it goes through the next process. I'll give this a shot though. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. The problem is that my dataset has thousands of rows, and 30-40 columns per table. I am trying to get one table in the correct format described, then union all the tables together. However, the only way I could do it was by using "UNION ALL", and I quickly reach the maximum string size with that approach

Comment: @user33484 . . . Insert the results into a temporary table, one table at a time.

Answer (score 0):

First you will have to unpivot both tables

```
/*UNPIVOT TABLE 1*/

SELECT  ID
       ,X3
       ,FIELD_NAME
       ,COLUMN_VALUE
       ,SOURCE_TABLE = 'TABLE 1'
INTO ##TB1
FROM 
    (SELECT ID,X1,X2,X3,X4
     FROM TABLE_1) AS P
UNPIVOT (COLUMN_VALUE 
         FOR FIELD_NAME IN (X1 , X2, X4)
        ) AS UNPVT

/*UNPIVOT TABLE 2*/

SELECT  ID 
       ,X3
       ,FIELD_NAME
       ,COLUMN_VALUE
       ,SOURCE_TABLE = 'TABLE 2'
INTO ##TB2
FROM 
    (SELECT ID,Y1,Y2,X3
     FROM TABLE_2) AS P
UNPIVOT (COLUMN_VALUE 
         FOR FIELD_NAME IN (Y1,Y2)
        ) AS UNPVT
```

Then use Union on both

```
/*DISTINCT UNION BOTH TABLES*/

    SELECT * 
    FROM ##TB2

    UNION

    SELECT * 
    FROM ##TB1
```

If you want to check microsoft [Pivot and unpivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017)

Also if you want to increase performance and you know that there are not duplicate results on joins i recommend you to use UNION ALL [Union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Access does not have unpivot unfortunately! Apologies for mislabelling - see my edit.

Comment: shame on me, sorry i didn't see it